How can I find contour or edges in my picture with opencv in Python3?

I want to detecting the three rectangles(white, gray, black) in this picture, like below image.

I tried to use find_contour function in opencv for Python, but the light gray stripes disturbed find objects.
I difficultly solved this but it was very tidy and boring work. I just adjusted the threshold of Canny function and erase overapped areas.

My code is the below code.
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src = cv2.imread('./src.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

canny_base = cv2.Canny(src, 10, 300)
canny_bot_base = cv2.Canny(src, 10, 250)
canny_top_bot = cv2.Canny(src, 10, 210)
canny_stripe = cv2.Canny(src, 10, 100)
canny_middle_top = cv2.Canny(src, 10, 50)

canny_bot = canny_bot_base - canny_base
canny_top = canny_top_bot - canny_bot_base
canny_middle = canny_middle_top - canny_stripe

contours_bot, hierachy = cv2.findContours(canny_bot.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contours_bot = sorted(contours_bot, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

pts_x_bot = []
pts_y_bot = []

for i in range(len(sorted_contours_bot)):
    contour_bot = sorted_contours_bot[i]

    extLeft = tuple(contour_bot[contour_bot[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(contour_bot[contour_bot[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(contour_bot[contour_bot[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(contour_bot[contour_bot[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

    pts_x_bot.append(extLeft[0]); pts_x_bot.append(extRight[0]); pts_x_bot.append(extBot[0]); pts_x_bot.append(extTop[0])
    pts_y_bot.append(extLeft[1]); pts_y_bot.append(extRight[1]); pts_y_bot.append(extBot[1]); pts_y_bot.append(extTop[1])


pts_x_top = []
pts_y_top = []

contours_top, hierachy = cv2.findContours(canny_top.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contours_top = sorted(contours_top, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for i in range(len(sorted_contours_top)):
    contour_top = sorted_contours_top[i]

    extLeft = tuple(contour_top[contour_top[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(contour_top[contour_top[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(contour_top[contour_top[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(contour_top[contour_top[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

    pts_x_top.append(extLeft[0]); pts_x_top.append(extRight[0]); pts_x_top.append(extBot[0]); pts_x_top.append(extTop[0])
    pts_y_top.append(extLeft[1]); pts_y_top.append(extRight[1]); pts_y_top.append(extBot[1]); pts_y_top.append(extTop[1])

pts_x_middle = []
pts_y_middle = []

contours_middle, hierachy = cv2.findContours(canny_middle.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contours_middle = sorted(contours_middle, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for i in range(len(sorted_contours_middle)):
    contour_middle = sorted_contours_middle[i]

    extLeft = tuple(contour_middle[contour_middle[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(contour_middle[contour_middle[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(contour_middle[contour_middle[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(contour_middle[contour_middle[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

    pts_x_middle.append(extLeft[0]); pts_x_middle.append(extRight[0]); pts_x_middle.append(extBot[0]); pts_x_middle.append(extTop[0])
    pts_y_middle.append(extLeft[1]); pts_y_middle.append(extRight[1]); pts_y_middle.append(extBot[1]); pts_y_middle.append(extTop[1])

plt.imshow(src, plt.cm.gray)
plt.colorbar()

plt.scatter(pts_x_bot, pts_y_bot, c = "r", s = 1)
plt.scatter(pts_x_top, pts_y_top, c = "blue", s = 1)
plt.scatter(pts_x_middle, pts_y_middle, c = "green", s = 1)

So I want to automation this code with any clustering algorithms such as DBSCAN or K-means. However, I could not know how apply these clustering algorithms in images. The examples of clustering that only find clusters in data points of two different features.
Could anybody tell how can I solve this problem?
